# How come we are being asked to review 8-month old posts?

Tags: bug

I saw the review queue blow out by about 20 extra items today. As I worked through the "new user's answer to an old question" I noticed that the posts themselves were quite old, for example:

[image: Example post]

Notice that this "new user's answer" is 8 months old! This is a bit late, is it not, to: "Watch for hidden gems, non-answers, and spam".

That should have been done in January!

---

(edit)

This seems relevant: [Can we raise the bar for reputation for late answers to bypass the review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue)

Comment: It's possible that this is the problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213020/late-late-answer